# Determine if language is regular

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

**Question.**

> Determine if the languages are regular:
>
> $L_{1}=\{(ab)^{k}a(ba)^{k}\,|\,k\geq0\}$
>
> $L_{2}=\{(ab)^{k}b(ba)^{k}\,|\,k\geq0\}$

I think both are not regular, I used the Pumping Lemma to prove, But the proof is exactly the same and it's a bit suspicious.
Is it true that both are not regular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$L_1$ is actually regular.  You can see this by regrouping terms as follows:

$L_{1}=\{a(ba)^{k}(ba)^{k}\,|\,k\geq0\}=\{a(ba)^{2k}\,|\,k\geq0\}=\{a(baba)^{*}\}$

$L_2$ appears to be non-regular, however.  The key observation is that the middle '$b$' in the expression appears to divide the strings in such a way as to force the left and right portions to have to balance (like parentheses).  There is probably a 'homomorphism'-based proof starting with the language $\{(^{k}b)^{k}\,|\,k\geq0\}$, mapping '$($' to '$ab$' and '$)$' to '$ba$'.  But I don't have time to formally verify this.

Comment: niceee thank you!